# Rationality of sum of reciprocals of irreducible polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory

(Sorry for my poor english..)

I have a question in number theory. (Just my curiosity)

Let $f(z)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial with degree is larger than or equal to 2.  Then is the number
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(n)}
\end{equation}
irrational? Or there is an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that this number is rational?

2. More generally, if for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f(x)$ and $f(x+n)$ are relativlely prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then is it true..?

I also know that proving the irrationality is very difficult, for example $\zeta(2k+1)$...

I could not find references about this problem.. Has this problem been proved? Or, is there a name for this problem?

Comment: To give an example showing that this is probably a very deep question in general: when $f(n)=n^2+1$, the series evaluates to $\big( \pi(e^{2\pi}+1)/(e^{2\pi}-1) - 1\big)/2$ (says Mathematica); and I don't believe that number is known to be irrational...!

Comment: @GregMartin You would think so, but you would actually be wrong! Algebraic relations between $\pi$ and $e^\pi$, or rather lack thereof, are much better understood that those between $\pi$ and $e$ - indeed, they are algebraically independent, rendering that number (provably!) transcendental. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Algebraic_independence_of_known_constants)

Comment: Is there any expectation that every absolutely convergent series of this form is an (exponential) period?  Or a trick to show this?

Comment: @Marty: For $f$ even and free of multiple roots, I think all is explained by the partial fraction expansion of the cotangent function. On all of the complex plane $\mathbb{C} \ni z$, we have $\pi \cot{\pi z = \lim_{N \to \infty}} \sum_{n = -N}^N \frac{1}{n+z}$.

Comment: So $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{f(n)}$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f(n)}$ @VesselinDimitrov